# Search results on https://stackexchange.com are broken because of "insecure content"

Tags: support, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com, ssl

The search results on https://stackexchange.com are blocked because of:

> [blocked] The page at https://stackexchange.com/search?q=https ran
>   insecure content from http://www.google.com/jsapi.

I am using Chrome.

Comment: No issue using safari or Firefox. Sounds like a chrome bug.

Comment: A [feature rather than a bug in Chrome, it would seem](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1342714)

Comment: I ran into this too, and don't recall deliberately typing "https" into the browser's location bar.  Dunno how I got the link ...

Comment: Any updates on this (been over 2 years already)

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** This now works correctly, we were waiting for Google to appropriately proxy the images through SSL/TLS, and this now occurs.

---

Previous: We don't support SSL *at this time*, you didn't get a link to `https://stackexchange.com` from us...the  error here is using that before it's ready :)

Comment: Any updates on this (been over 2 years already)

Comment: -1 When I encountered this issue ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260117/171535 ), I was switched to SSL through the Stack Exchange site, so your comment is not correct for all cases.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular thanks for the poke - you're correct (a lot changes in 3 years :) and this should now be supported. It is since a build a few minutes ago.