# Searching stackexchange.com displays "Loading" and doesn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ssl

The content of the page just says "Loading".

The URL I tried to load was:
https://stackexchange.com/search?q=car+stereo

Am using Chromium browser Version 43.0.2357.81 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17.1 (64-bit).

The developer tools console shows the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://stackexchange.com/search?q=car+stereo' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script 'http://www.google.com/jsapi'. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Screenshot:
[image]

Further important details: I had just recently logged in, with that browser tab, using my Google account. Looking at the browser history, the https comes from that point. I didn't initially try to load the site through https.

Comment: True, Stack Exchange does not support ssl, this is just one of many examples of broken things if you by mistake land on the https version. Browse http://stackexchange.com/search?q=car%2Bstereo and all will work, though not secure.

Comment: Also, how did you land on https://stackexchange.com (the ssl version) to begin with? If you followed a link, it should be changed to  http://stackexchange.com which is the actual working site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I had just recently logged in, with that browser tab, using my Google account. Looking at the browser history, the https comes from that point. I didn't initially try to load the site through https.

Comment: I see. So the actual bug is having the login redirect to the non supported https:// version.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, that's a reasonable conclusion. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard but I don't think the fix is to redirect from secure to insecure, right?

Comment: @rene real fix is to support https but we both know it's not going to happen (at least in the next 6-8 years) so...

Comment: We agree on that ... @ShadowWizard

Comment: This flaw is ongoing ... band-aid is to just avoid doing any search inside stackexchange itself and instead do all searching directly from google which is fine it just means stackexchanges fails to have available such search pattern traffic from which it could build a better UI experience someday

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd your 6-8 years prediction is a little too long  compared to the time it actually took

Comment: @Ferrybig yeah, one of those times when I am happy to be wrong. :)