# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/

Tags: bug, status-norepro, web-sockets

[Searching for mariadb](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=mariadb) I got the above error message (started happening ~21:00 UTC, still happening at 21:37). [Websockets are working fine](http://websocketstest.com/result/624954), so I'm not sure what this could be...

Comment: There is some maintenance going on so that might interfer: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/656569338346868736

Comment: More than likely just bad timing. I am not sure this is an issue any longer, you probably hit it just at the wrong time.

Comment: Actually, the issue here is the https. [this](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=mariadb) works just fine.

Comment: Looks like [the issue that caused this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156353/search-results-on-https-stackexchange-com-are-broken-because-of-insecure-cont) has now been fixed.

Comment: Yep, works now.